# If I can use the components by installing syncfusion as a module in my angular project, then why do I need o download and use the Installer

Tags: syncfusion

I registered for syncfusion trial for 1 month free, It asks me to download install  file, My question is  if I can use the components by installing syncfusion as a module in my angular project, then why do I need to download and use the Installer.

If I just reference in my package.json and do npm i I am able to use it. In this case where do I put my license

Answer (score 2):

You need the license so that they can keep an eye on you if you are making more than 1 million USD.

however you don't need to download the installer, just import `registerLicense` like so and then put your API key within the `registerLicense('api key')` and you're good to use the component without any popup on the application.

```
import { registerLicense } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base'

registerLicense('api key');
```

You can grab the API key from your syncfusion dashboard "Downloads and keys" -> "Get License key".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download our npm package. However, to use our package legally they needed to get license from us by visiting syncfusion.com and signing up for license. This is also mentioned in our licensing document in npm package. Please find its content from GitHub link
Link: https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-javascript-ui-controls/blob/master/controls/grids/license

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/installation/

Online Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/grid/overview

We don’t have any source level license validation, so you don’t have to do anything in your application for license validation. Our current license validation are fully based on support and new feature requests.

Please get back to us if you require any more assistance on this.